# When you have a m-to-m with two Aggregrate Roots of a third association, how do you filter the third association?

Tags: design-patterns, many-to-many, domain-driven-design

I have the following 3 domain objects: `Competition`, `Season`, and `Match`

`Competition` has many `Seasons`
`Season` has many `competitions`
`Competition` is the aggregate root for `Season` because a `Season` cannot exist without a `Competition`

Examples:
`Competition`:
Premiership -> Season 1, Season 2
FA Cup -> Season 1, Season 2
League Cup -> Season 1, Season 2

`Season`:
Season 1 -> Premiership, FA Cup, League Cup
Season 2 -> Premiership, FA Cup, League Cup

`Competition` also has many `Matches`
`Season` also has many `Matches`

`competition->getMatches()` returns all `matches` for every `season`
`season->getMatches()` returns all `matches` for every `competition`

**Question.** In the context of DDD what is the best way to get all matches for a combination of competition and season? For example, matches just from Premiership Season 1?

As far as I am aware there are 3 approaches:

1. Pass in `Season` into `Premiership->getMatches(Season)` with a loop find
   `Competition` with that `Season`, then with another loop find `Matches`
   belonging to both the selected `Competition` and the passed in `Season`. The same principle can be applied vice versa `Season 1->getMatches(Competition)`. But what about perfomrance?
2. Implement the Temporal Pattern.
3. Just create in repository/dao/whatever a method to `findMatchesByCompetitionAndSeason(Competition, Season)` but doesn't this defeat the purpose of DDD?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

> `Competition` is the aggregate root for `Season` because a `Season` cannot exist without a `Competition`.

I don't know the specifics of your domain, but this statement doesn't sound right somehow. And after reading the rest of your question, I think this is where the problem lies.

> Season 1 -> Premiership, FA Cup, League Cup

This indicates that `Season` is clearly a shared thing. So making a season part of the `Competition` aggregate root is not a good idea. Try to redesign your model so that `Season` can live on its own (i.e. make it its own aggregate root) and reference it from `Competition`.

With regards to your last question: You won't get around implementing specific finders in your repository for performance reasons. This doesn't defeat the purpose of DDD, because the finder still uses domain terminology and works with domain objects. It is just a technical thing that returns the right domain objects for your use case, and as such, is **not** part of your domain.